# AutoComplete text box ----No values found

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have implemented an autoComplete textbox using jquery function and am fetching the suggest values from DB. Everything looks fine.

But if no matching data found i want to display some user friendly message saying " No match found" to the user and clear the textbox. how can i implement this ?

added the currnt code

```
function txtAutoComplete(acUrl, minLength, txtbxId) {
    $("#" + txtbxId).autocomplete({
        minLength: minLength, 
        source: function (request, responseFn) {
                $.post(acUrl, null, function (resp) {
                var txtValue = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + txtValue, "i");
                var a = $.grep(resp, function (item, index) {
                    return matcher.test(item);
                });
                responseFn(a);
            });
        }
```

Thanks to Yuriy Rozhovetskiy.

```
var error = 'No match';
if (a.length == 0) {
    responseFn(error);
}
else {
    responseFn(a);
}
```

But the Error suggestion is displayed Vertically how can i make it to display like a normal autosuggest.
Thanks

Comment: you can implement this by using the javascript and css rules and html markup and (maybe) server side technology (of your choice), may be there is a pre build support for showing custom messages.... P.S please show some code that you have tried. how we are supposed to guess the name of the plugin ???

Comment: have a look to autocompletes combbox.. i think this is what you need  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: What is your current code/what plugin are you using?

Comment: @Sudhir yes i tried and posted code. My doubt what if no search found and i want to display user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this staff in source function:

```
source: function (request, responseFn) {
    $.post(acUrl, null, function (resp) {
        var txtValue = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + txtValue, "i");
        var a = $.grep(resp, function (item, index) {
            return matcher.test(item);
        });

        if(a.length == 0){
            alert("No matches found");
            $("#" + txtbxId).val("");
        }
        responseFn(a);
    });
}
```

Comment: i don want to show this in an alert. I want to send that as a response which will be shown to the user. I tried but it is getting displayed vertically ?  Edited my question with code

Answer (score 1):

Changed my code as suggested by Yuriy Rozhovetskiy with little modification to send JSON that worked

```
var error = ["No match"];
if (a.length == 0) {
    responseFn(error);
}
else {
    responseFn(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return this value in the script which returns the value.

Instead of returning nothing, just check if you have some values and if not return an array with one value containing the "No matches found"-Value.

Comment: What you said is logical, but how do you solve the problem related to selectness of `"No matches found"` element? You need to disable it somehow